# Looping with If condition in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, cursor

I created this block to test three conditions from a table called process. I created the sql query based on the requirements and I inserted it into a FOR LOOP that should return more than a value every time I test a date which matches the date in the process table. My problems with this block is -First: When I test invalid date against the DATE_PO records, I get the ELSE condition, but this starts to loop twice for the number of records in the table process:

```
anonymous block completed
No records made in this date !
No records made in this date !
```

The second problem, if no data in this table, how do I make an appropriate  condition to test and display a message to the user of no records found?

Table process

```
       NUM        DATE_PO      STATUS                                    
    ----------  -----------   -----------
      1243      21-DEC-15       CANCEL                                 
      5678      21-DEC-15       APPROVE




BEGIN
  FOR X IN
  (SELECT PO.STATUS,
    PO.DATE_PO,
    SUM(D.QUANTIY) QUANTITY_SUM,
    SUM(NVL(D.QUANTIY,0) * NVL (M.COST,0)) T_VALUE
    FROM PROCESS.PO, DELETE_PROCESS, MONEY M
    WHERE D.PO = M.PO
    AND PO.NUM  = D.NUM
    GROUP BY PO.STATUS, PO.DATE_PO)
 LOOP
   IF  TO_CHAR(X.DATE_PO, 'mm-yyyy') ='10-2015' THEN --Not valid date
     IF X.STATUS ='CANCEL' THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CANCELLATIONS: ' || X.QUANTITY_SUM );
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALUE: '|| X.T_VALUE);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE: ' || X.DATE_PO );
    ELSIF X.STATUS ='HOLD' THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HOLDS: ' || X.QUANTITY_SUM );
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALUE: '|| X.T_VALUE);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE: ' || X.DATE_PO );
    ELSIF X.STATUS = 'APPROVE' THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('APPROVES: ' || X.QUANTITY_SUM );
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALUE: '|| X.T_VALUE);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE: ' || X.DATE_PO );
    END IF;
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No records made in this date !');
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. Hope it helps. Though its not the best solution as it can be
>   done without using ROW-BY-ROW processing. Bulk COLLECT option can also
>   be used. Let me know if this helps. Since i dont have workspace please
>   pardon any syntax erros if any.

```
DECLARE
  lv_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
  lv_date VARCHAR2(10):='12-2015';
  lv_dt DATE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT TO_DATE(lv_date,'MM-YYYY') INTO lv_dt FROM DUAL;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Not a valid Date');
    RETURN;
  END;
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO lv_cnt
  FROM
    (SELECT PO.STATUS,
      PO.DATE_PO,
      SUM(D.QUANTIY) QUANTITY_SUM,
      SUM(NVL(D.QUANTIY,0) * NVL (M.COST,0)) T_VALUE
    FROM PROCESS.PO,
      DELETE_PROCESS,
      MONEY M
    WHERE D.PO = M.PO
    AND PO.NUM = D.NUM
    GROUP BY PO.STATUS,
      PO.DATE_PO
    )A;

  IF lv_cnt > 0 THEN

    FOR X IN
    (SELECT PO.STATUS,
      PO.DATE_PO,
      SUM(D.QUANTIY) QUANTITY_SUM,
      SUM(NVL(D.QUANTIY,0) * NVL (M.COST,0)) T_VALUE
    FROM PROCESS.PO,
      DELETE_PROCESS,
      MONEY M
    WHERE D.PO = M.PO
    AND PO.NUM = D.NUM
    GROUP BY PO.STATUS,
      PO.DATE_PO
    )
    LOOP
      IF X.STATUS ='CANCEL' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CANCELLATIONS: ' || X.QUANTITY_SUM );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALUE: '|| X.T_VALUE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE: ' || X.DATE_PO );
      ELSIF X.STATUS ='HOLD' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HOLDS: ' || X.QUANTITY_SUM );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALUE: '|| X.T_VALUE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE: ' || X.DATE_PO );
      ELSIF X.STATUS = 'APPROVE' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('APPROVES: ' || X.QUANTITY_SUM );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALUE: '|| X.T_VALUE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE: ' || X.DATE_PO );
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  ELSIF lv_cnt = 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No records found for the user');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it throws exception the second select statement i think (ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement)

Comment: My.bad.forgot.to.add.into.clause.:P. Check Now

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, I inserted the right dates in the from the table, but it goes to the exception                                        anonymous block completed
Not a valid Date

Comment: Can.u.give.date example u r  trying? You have a fixed date format?

Comment: This is what I used!    V_DATE DATE :=TO_DATE('12-2015', 'mm-yyyy'); I disabled the exception and the error says 01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range

Comment: Let it V_DATE be a varchar field. Since it is parsed again in DATE in the SELECT call. Try passing V_DATE VARCHAR2(10) :='12-2015'

Comment: I did but the loop is not testing in both cases i.e. i set the date to 10- 2015, as it should go to else condition, but it looped as the records are true!

Comment: OK..so.got  your point now. Date should be full format like dd-mm.yyyy? Anthing except that shold be invalid. As per your question TO_CHAR(X.DATE_PO, 'mm-yyyy') ='10-2015' this is not valid date?

Comment: Is there any efficient way that I can pass a date of (mm-yyyy) to this cursor and compare based on the dates in the table? It's only because this cursor is part of my procedure where I only pass date using this format?

Comment: Actually this can be done bypure sql only..That will be most efficient.

Comment: The problem its part of a procedure! If it is possible in SQL, how do I alter?

Comment: I've never used a refcursor before! I am only a newbie to this business